# Git push stuck at 99%

Tags: git

What do you do when you've added too many large binary files (PSDs) and tried to push, and git gets stuck at 99%?

```
$ git push origin dev
Counting objects: 4790, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects:  99% (4504/4512)
```

git is currently using 2.7 gigs of memory and climbing. It was 2.0 when I started typing this question. I think I'll kill it and hope someone knows a good solution.

Comment: `du -ah` shows 695M on my assets directory and 1.7G on root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How long did you wait? If you have a lot of large files, it may take a while to push. If you really need to cancel the push, you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to stop it.

Comment: I gave it about 15 minutes. It was slowly eating up all my memory though and was just sitting at 99% the whole time.

Comment: If you have huge files (695MB of files, 1.7GB repo) it might take a while (and a fair amount of memory) to compress all the objects. To be honest, Git isn't amazing at handling enormous binary files; I usually keep those in a separate directory and use `rsync` to move them between servers/machines, and create `symlinks` to the downloaded media content.

Comment: Stuck at 99% for 15 minutes and ever increasing memory usage doesn't look good. You think it'll eventually succeed if I left it running over lunch? I suppose it can't hurt to try.

Comment: And regarding moving files around: access to the files is easy. I'd like my git repo to include the designs for archival purposes though.

Comment: It is a pretty memory-intensive operation; I can believe it might chew up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 5):

I see this is an old post, but for the record:

I suspect this is because of delta-compression of the binary files, and you can modify .gitattributes to tell git not to run delta-compression on given file extensions.

See: [git pull without remotely compressing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102053/git-pull-without-remotely-compressing-objects)