# git pull without remotely compressing objects

Tags: git

I have a repository full of zip files, re-compressing theses files will be a waste of time.

I've tried to set *core.compression = 0* on the remote and the local copy without success

```
git config core.compression 0
git config core.loosecompression 0
```

*git pull* still do

```
remote: Counting objects: 23, done.
remote: Compressing objects: ...
```

Comment: Have you measured the difference in performance? I wouldn't worry about time spent compressing already-compressed data; networks are likely much slower than your CPU.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The time problem I had was caused by delta compression.

The solution for me was

```
echo '*.zip -delta' > .gitattributes
git gc
```

I will quote this excellent response
from [Re: serious performance issues with images, audio files, and other "non-code" data](https://public-inbox.org/git/20100514051049.GF6075@coredump.intra.peff.net/):

> Git does spend a fair bit of time in zlib for some workloads, but it
> should not create problems on the order of minutes.
>
> For pushing and pulling, you're probably seeing delta compression,
> which can be slow for large files
>
> ```
>  core.compression 0   # Didn't seem to work.
> ```
>
> That should disable zlib compression of loose objects and objects
> within packfiles. It can save a little time for objects which won't
> compress, but you will lose the size benefits for any text files.
>
> But it won't turn off delta compression, which is what the
> "compressing..." phase during push and pull is doing. And which is
> much more likely the cause of slowness.
>
> ```
>  pack.window 0
> ```
>
> It sets the number of other objects git will consider when doing delta
> compression. Setting it low should improve your push/pull times. But
> you will lose the substantial benefit of delta-compression of your
> non-image files (and git's meta objects). So the "-delta" option above
> for specific files is a much better solution.
>
> ```
>  echo '*.jpg -delta' >> .gitattributes
> ```
>
> Also, consider repacking your repository, which will generate a
> packfile that will be re-used during push and pull.

Note that the settings have to be made on the repo you are fetching/pulling from, not the one you are fetching/pulling to.

Comment: suggest using ">>" since this will overwrite anything else you might already have in your `.gitattributes` file: `echo '*.zip -delta' >> .gitattributes`

Answer (score 8):

The `compressing object` line means it is do the `pack`ing  work.  That include diffing the trees and stuff.   It is not "compressing" in the sense of `core.compression`.

Comment: @Doud You don't. Git packs things. This is good and desirable behaviour.

Comment: @Doud how do I move my house without packing?

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ When I serve my git folder via http git fetch/pull don't pack anything. Maybe you should try to serve your house via http.

Comment: @Doud, Indeed, the old (non-smart) http don't pack stuff. But it (almost always) use more bandwidth --- it (almost always) send old commit you don't need.

Comment: FYI, The 'compressing object' line is the call to 'git pack-objects' and have nothing to do with 'diffing the trees and stuff' also 'core.compression' and 'pack.compression' will affect the packing work

Comment: so how do disable packing the whole git repo on git clone? i have no problems with bandwidth

Answer (score 2):

This is useful if your remote server has very limited ram. SSH to the remote server go to the repository then run:

```
git config --add core.bigFileThreshold 1
```

This will turn off delta compression. if you want to undo it:

```
git config --unset core.bigFileThreshold
```