# How to disable compression in git server side?

Tags: git

I have a repo from which pull takes forever because the server has little free RAM and it is swapping a lot while

```
remote: Compressing objects: 24%
```

is happening (even if I clone locally on the server). The network is not that constrained, so it would be fine to send all data uncompressed. How can I do that?

Comment: You can try playing with `pack.*` options in [git-config](http://man.he.net/man1/git-config).

Comment: `echo '*.zip -delta' >>.gitattributes` to disable compression for zip files. see also [git pull without remotely compressing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102053/git-pull-without-remotely-compressing-objects)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the git documentation:

> ```
>  core.bigFileThreshold  
>
>     Files larger than this size are stored deflated, without
>     attempting delta compression.  Storing large files without
>     delta compression avoids excessive memory usage, at the
>     slight expense of increased disk usage.
>
> Default is 512 MiB on all platforms.
> This should be reasonable for most projects as source code and other 
> text files can still be delta compressed, 
> but larger binary media files won't be.
>
> Common unit suffixes of 'k', 'm', or 'g' are supported.
> ```

So I guess by setting this value to something like 1 would do the trick.

*Extended by comments: you can set this with a `git config --add core.bigFileThreshold 1` command. It works for bare repos as well.*

Comment: I have a bare repo on the server side. Can I just go there and edit the config?

Comment: I guess so, or run:

`git config --add core.bigFileThreshold 1`