# Disabling compression for git local pulls

Tags: git

If I have a 'local remote' (eg `git remote add local /some/dir`) and pull from it, git will still compress before copying data.

This compression can take longer than the copy, dependant on disk/CPU load.
Is there a way to disable compression for local file operations only?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483288/how-to-disable-compression-in-git-server-side) will help

Comment: @clmno Thanks, the downside to that (or disabling 'core.compression') would be increased disk usage for those repos and pulls from these repos from other networked machines would also have compression disabled.  Perhaps it could be used in a script to achieve the goal though..