# Git rev-list cannot find commit

Tags: git

When I run:

```
git verify-pack -v .git\objects\pack\pack-*.idx
```

one of the lines in the output contains:

```
651302358b781ab60f364416272e1c35107c974f blob   23980089 23987383 699599322
```

But if I try to lookup that blob with:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | grep 651302358b781ab60f364416272e1c35107c974f
```

or:

```
 git rev-list --all --reflog --objects | grep 651302358b781ab60f364416272e1c35107c974f
```

I just get an empty result. Should I not be able to look up any blobs returned by `verify-pack`?

Based on below I have tried to: create a fresh clone, run `git repack` run `git gc` but same result.

Answer (score 2):

The object may be abandoned, i.e., its last reference(s), whatever they were, are now gone.  Because the object is in a pack file, however, it cannot simply be removed.  Git must build an entirely new pack.

If you use `git repack` to build new pack files, any unreferenced objects will be omitted from the new packs.  (Note that `git gc` will do this automatically.  However, `.keep` files may keep the old packs around, if you have created `.keep` files.)

**Edit**: as [jthill points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735591/git-rev-list-cannot-find-commit/37735662?noredirect=1#comment62944463_37735662), you must repack with `-a` or `-A` to consolidate older packs.  While automatic `git gc` will supply `-A` in some cases, it's [only when the number of pack files exceeds `gc.autoPackLimit`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html), which [defaults to 50](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Comment: I did try with git gc but it had no effect, still git verify-pack finds the blob that cannot be looked up with rev-list. And git repack gives "Nothing new to pack". I also tried to clone again, same "ghost" object exists.

Comment: Perhaps it's referenced from a reflog entry.  Try `git rev-list --all --reflogs` for the lookup step (keeping `--objects` as well).  Although, if it shows up on initial `clone`, that's a bit odd, since clone does not copy reflogs.

Comment: $ git rev-list --all --reflogs --objects | grep 651302358b781ab60f364416272e1c35107c974f  does not work. Seems rev-list does not know --reflogs option

Comment: Oops, sorry, typo: `--reflog` (singular), not `--reflogs` (plural).

Comment: I don't know what else to try at this point, but I will be curious to see what is going on.

Comment: repack's manpage mentions you need  `-a`  or `-A` to go dig through the past.

Comment: @jthill: aha, and `git gc` only supplies `-A` if the pack count exceeds `gc.autoPackLimit`.  According to git-config(1), the default is 50 packs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this at the bottom of git help stash, to find unreferenced commits.

```
git fsck --unreachable |
grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 |
xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would check if that reference is still in that idx file after

```sh
git gc
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

Use Git 2.32 (Q2 2021) considering:

- [`git repack` is much faster now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66832213/6309)
- `git rev-list` has new options since 2016

See [commit 14e7b83](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14e7b8344f0b7349b914331c0aff18f73faf03da) (19 Mar 2021), [commit 2a15964](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2a15964128edd08278efeacc75e75c77cfdde77e), [commit 13d746a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13d746a303592068826824b30c47941fb328c8a7), [commit dab3247](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dab324773422f38f8572185127a268813342805e), [commit f25e33c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f25e33c1566fecb097a460f0649ac1a20c418843) (05 Mar 2021), and [commit 0fabafd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fabafd0b948bfc1c07db73494863d581c7f5d04), [commit 339bce2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/339bce27f4f2a6f3bfab3e708429c810f4030c43), [commit c9fff00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9fff0001699dd2862bf350146631fe53c1226d9), [commit f62312e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f62312e02837d91e3b47ea876654bf3ac97b2905) (22 Feb 2021) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
See [commit ccae01c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccae01cab817f64a52fcb403cb355e41c2303b74) (05 Mar 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 20b031f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20b031fedeeb6e8df428b6b7cdc05c14375cd1e1), [commit 6325da1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6325da14af2b76585a72cf639fa08e4cb1a370c8), [commit fbf20ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbf20aeeef062e8cbd7db43788cfd3a69764071f), [commit 60bb5f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60bb5f2f5d0c8a71254f31fa5d3d3fe42792aaf8) (22 Feb 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2744383](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2744383cbda9bbbe4219bd3532757ae6d28460e1), 24 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`revision`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9fff0001699dd2862bf350146631fe53c1226d9): learn '--no-kept-objects'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jeff King</sup>

> A future caller will want to be able to perform a reachability traversal which terminates when visiting an object found in a kept pack.
> The closest existing option is '`--honor-pack-keep`', but this isn't quite what we want.
> Instead of halting the traversal midway through, a full traversal is always performed, and the results are only trimmed afterwords.
>
> Besides needing to introduce a new flag (since culling results post-facto can be different than halting the traversal as it's happening), there is an additional wrinkle handling the distinction in-core and on-disk kept packs.
> That is: what kinds of kept pack should stop the traversal?
>
> Introduce '`--no-kept-objects[=<on-disk|in-core>]`' to specify which kinds of kept packs, if any, should stop a traversal.
> This can be useful for callers that want to perform a reachability analysis, but want to leave certain packs alone (for e.g., when doing a geometric repack that has some "large" packs which are kept in-core that it wants to leave alone).

Note: This is an "internal-use" option only, but interesting to know about, to experiment in your case.