# Why is git repo getting bigger when cloning with file protocol

Tags: git

I have a repo in a samba share, which has 1.2 G in .git/objects.
When I clone that repo with file:// protocol locally, then the cloned repo gets 1.5 GB in .git/objects.
Why is Git doing this to me?

Then I tried it on another repo, which is smaller. I see in the stdout that Git is always recompressing a part of the repo in file:// protocol, which may be the reason, but with https protocol from github thats not happening.

https protocol from github to local repo2:

```
git clone https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git ~/repo2
19:39:56.188035 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git' 'repo2'
Klone nach 'repo2' ...
19:39:56.211036 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git'
19:39:57.381345 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'fetch-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--stdin' '--lock-pack' '--thin' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--cloning' 'https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git/'
19:39:57.400372 exec_cmd.c:116          trace: exec: 'git' 'fetch-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--stdin' '--lock-pack' '--thin' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--cloning' 'https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git/'
19:39:57.412380 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'fetch-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--stdin' '--lock-pack' '--thin' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--cloning' 'https://github.com/someuser/somerepo.git/'
remote: Counting objects: 73839, done.
19:39:57.951242 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 122 on SAJTY' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--pack_header=2,73839'
19:39:57.960749 exec_cmd.c:116          trace: exec: 'git' 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 122 on SAJTY' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--pack_header=2,73839'
19:39:57.976259 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 122 on SAJTY' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--pack_header=2,73839'
remote: Total 73839 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 73839
Empfange Objekte: 100% (73839/73839), 21.96 MiB | 112.00 KiB/s, Fertig.
Löse Unterschiede auf: 100% (60640/60640), Fertig.
19:44:31.187832 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Prüfe Konnektivität'
19:44:31.190358 exec_cmd.c:116          trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Prüfe Konnektivität'
19:44:31.195362 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Prüfe Konnektivität'
remote: Total 73839 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 73839
```

file protocol from local repo2 to repo3:

```
git clone file://$HOME/repo2 ~/repo3
19:46:53.852660 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'clone' 'file:///home/sajty/repo2' 'repo3'
Klone nach 'repo3' ...
19:46:53.874679 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'git-upload-pack '\''/home/sajty/repo2'\'''
19:46:53.878697 run-command.c:209       trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'git-upload-pack '\''/home/sajty/repo2'\''' 'git-upload-pack '\''/home/sajty/repo2'\'''
19:46:53.903236 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 129 on SAJTY' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
19:46:53.903236 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'pack-objects' '--revs' '--thin' '--stdout' '--progress' '--delta-base-offset'
19:46:53.907238 exec_cmd.c:116          trace: exec: 'git' 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 129 on SAJTY' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
remote: 19:46:53.910226 exec_cmd.c:116          trace: exec: 'git' 'pack-objects' '--revs' '--thin' '--stdout' '--progress' '--delta-base-offset'
19:46:53.915230 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 129 on SAJTY' '--check-self-contained-and-connected'
remote: 19:46:53.918234 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--revs' '--thin' '--stdout' '--progress' '--delta-base-offset'
remote: Zähle Objekte: 72156, Fertig.
remote: Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (12623/12623), Fertig.
remote: Total 72156 (delta 59287), reused 72156 (delta 59287)
Empfange Objekte: 100% (72156/72156), 21.65 MiB | 16.91 MiB/s, Fertig.
Löse Unterschiede auf: 100% (59287/59287), Fertig.
19:46:57.648781 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Prüfe Konnektivität'
19:46:57.653804 exec_cmd.c:116          trace: exec: 'git' 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Prüfe Konnektivität'
19:46:57.658788 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Prüfe Konnektivität'
```

So how do I disable recompression when cloning with file:// protocol?
This wastes HDD space and cloning takes 1 minute longer. I dont understand it.
I just want to have the same packfile as on github.

Note1: I know about the --local option, which disables recompression, but then I dont see progress/download speed, which is even worse on a big repo with slow network connection.

Note2: I'm using default packing and gc settings and I could reproduce this with multiple repos on different PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and see if a clone without compression is quicker without compression:

```
git -c core.compression=0 clone ...
```

See [`git config core.compression`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corecompression):

> An integer -1..9, indicating the compression level for objects that are not in a pack file.
>   -1 is the zlib default.
>   0 means no compression, and 1..9 are various speed/size tradeoffs, 9 being slowest.
>   If not set, defaults to core.compression. If that is not set, defaults to 1 (best speed).

Also make sure to use the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.12 is available since today, Feb. 2017)

See also "[git pull without remotely compressing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153033/6309)":

> `core.compression 0` should disable zlib compression of loose objects and objects within packfiles. It can save a little time for objects which won't compress, but you will lose the size benefits for any text files.
>   **But it won't turn off delta compression**, which is what the "`Compressing...`" phase during push and pull is doing. And which is much more likely the cause of slowness.
>
> [`pack.window 0`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-packwindow) sets the number of other objects git will consider when doing delta compression. Setting it low should improve your push/pull times.
>   But you will lose the substantial benefit of delta-compression of your non-image files (and git's meta objects).

So you can try also:

```
git -c pack.window=0 clone ...
```

The conclusion is that, while you can avoid the "Compressing" phase, this is not recommended.
It is better to [disable `delta` for certain files only through a `.gitattributes` directive](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_packing_objects) rather than removing delta compression for a all repo.